# SQLAlchemy Query Datetime Manipulation

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Slightly stuck with how to do this in sqlalchemy.

For example I'd like to compare is end_date + 10 days + 90 days greater than or equal to today.

My current query is below but am unsure how to make this work in SQLAlchemy

Campaign.end_date is a date, Campaign.expiry_end_date and Campaign.claim_pending_period_days are integers.

```
.filter(
  Campaign.end_date + Campaign.expiry_end_date + Campaign.claim_pending_period_days >= date.today()
)
```

Comment: That should work as is, if I'm not mistaken. `date` + `integer` adds days to the date in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -1):

Convert Campaign.expiry_end_date and Campaign.claim_pending_period_days to datetime object. It will be easy to add and compare dates

`Campaign.end_date + datetime.timedelta(days=Campaign.expiry_end_date)+datetime.timedelta(days=Campaign.claim_pending_period_days)`